# New column for sequential rows in a loop in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to create a new column based on values in sequential rows. I have the following data frame where there are two subjects in the subject column and I would like to compare each row in the trial column to the row preceding it for each subject.

```
df <- data.frame(subject = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
             trial = c("switch", "noswitch", "switch", "switch", "noswitch", "switch", "switch", "noswitch", "noswitch", "noswitch"))
```

I'm trying to use an if statement to look behind one row, then create a new column based on the 4 possible configurations of two sequential rows: switch-switch, noswitch-noswitch, noswitch-switch, switch-noswitch. The new column would be populated by a name for those four configurations: comp, incomp, noswitch_incomp, switch_comp, respectively. The loop would start over for the new subject, so the first index would be NA because there is no preceding value. So far I have the following:

```
for(i in seq.int(unique(df$subject))){ 
  df$results <- if(df$switch == "switch" & lag(df$switch, 1) == "switch"){
    "comp" 
    } else if (df$switch == "noswitch" & lag(df$switch, 1) == "noswitch"){
      "incomp"
    } else if (df$switch == "noswitch" & lag(df$switch, 1) == "switch"){
      "noswitch_incomp"
    } else {
      "switch_comp" 
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error which I think has something to do with the if statement not evaluating the arguments within:

```
   Error in if (df$switch == "switch" & lag(df$switch, 1) == "switch") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I've tried using mutate() with dplyr to match conditions but similar errors occur. Is there another function I could try to evaluate these conditions?

Comment: Could you add what the desired output should be?

Comment: `switch` isn't a column in `df`, so `df$switch` is `NULL`, which is of length 0. That's where the error comes from.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I would still get an error message with the following. The answer below using dplyr::case_when with group_by(subject) fixed my issues. Thanks for the input! Error in if (df$switch == "switch" & lag(df$switch, 1) == "switch") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::case_when`.

```
df %>% group_by(subject) %>%
  mutate(results = case_when(
    trial == 'switch' & lag(trial) == 'switch' ~ 'comp',
    trial == 'noswitch' & lag(trial) == 'noswitch' ~ 'incomp',
    trial == 'noswitch' & lag(trial) == 'switch' ~ 'noswitch_incomp',
    trial == 'switch' & lag(trial) == 'noswitch' ~ 'switch_comp'
  ))

# # A tibble: 10 x 3
# # Groups:   subject [2]
#    subject trial    results     
#      <dbl> <chr>    <chr>          
#  1      1. switch   NA             
#  2      1. noswitch noswitch_incomp
#  3      1. switch   switch_comp    
#  4      1. switch   comp           
#  5      1. noswitch noswitch_incomp
#  6      2. switch   NA             
#  7      2. switch   comp           
#  8      2. noswitch noswitch_incomp
#  9      2. noswitch incomp         
# 10      2. noswitch incomp
```

Comment: You need to add `group_by(subject)`

Comment: Got it, @NathanWerth. Thanks!

Comment: This worked seamlessly on the toy dataset here and the larger one as well! Thank you so much!